# for loop in Flex 3

Tags: flex3, for-loop, mxml

i want to create a loop withing my mxml code to create a variable number of input fields based on an integer value , this value is the result of a call which gets the number of columns in a database table.

i have tried to use the repeater component however it needs an array, and my call is an int.

Is there something in flex mxml whcih can take an int and then loop as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a function that builds the array you need based on the integer, and feeding the resulting array to the repeater.

I hope that helps, no time for more right now ;)